# NVIDIA 740M and ubuntu 13.10

Tags: nvidia, 13.10, asus

My laptop (Asus X550LB) has a NVIDIA 740M. I have tried installing bumblebee but every time I check "About This Computer" in the graphics part it says Intel Haswell Mobile. Does that mean that I'm not using my graphics card ? How can I make it work ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bumblebee is there to allow you to selectively use your GPU. If bumblebee is correctly installed, you can execute -

```
$ primusrun firefox
```

and a Firefox process will be started that will use your GPU. This lets you use your GPU only for programs that need it e.g. Games, Video player etc.

Comment: After using that command would i be using my GPU for Google Chrome (Changing firefox to google-chrome) ? Can I use also for VLC ? Thanks

Comment: Whatever program you run like this would use the GPU until you exit it.

Comment: Is there a way to always use it with out having to write that code again ?

Comment: No. Prefixing that command is what let's you use the GPU selectively. Remember, the point of Bumblebee is selective use of GPU. You choose when your GPU is used. That way you also save power consumption.

Comment: You can edit the .desktop files for a particular program to always execute that primusrun command when you click in a menu option for, say, Google Chrome.